# I want to populate a second select form based on the first one selection. Both are retrieving their elements from an sql database

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is my first post here.
I'm less than beginner in HTML or Java script, I'm doing this only from a month or so.
So, this is my first project.
I need to populate two select forms with data retrieved from a SQL database.
First select is a "Car brand" second one is "Car model" which is based on the first one.
I have managed to populate the first select and to get the selected value in java script variable x.
How should I proceed do next to read the models from the selected brand?

Here is what I have done until now:

```
<?php
include("sql.php"); //connection to the database
$sql_select_marca = "select id, denumire from marca"; //sql statement to   retrieve brands
$stmtMarca = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql_select_marca);
?>

<html>
<title> Adauga Oferta </title>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>

<form cars style="position: absolute">
<p> Marca:</p>
<select id=SelectBrand class="select" name="marcaSelectata" 
form="cars" style="position: absolute" onchange="marca()">
<option value="">Select brand</Seleteaza> </option>
<?php
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtMarca)) {
echo '<option  value=' . $row['id'] . '>' . $row['denumire'] . '</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<p style="margin-left: 290px"> Model:</p>
<select id="SelectModel" class="select" name="model" form="cars" style="position: absolute;margin-left: 360px" onchange="model()" >
<option value="">Select model</Seleteaza> </option>
</select>
</form>

<p id="Brand"> You've selected:</p>

<script>
function marca() {
var x = document.getElementById("SelectBrand").value;
document.getElementById("Marca").innerHTML = "Ai selectat: " + x;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The second select from database should be something like:

```
select * from model where idmarca = $x 
*where x is the id read from the first select
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it with ajax. on Car brand select change you need to make a ajax call to list the second select box values.
For Example refer [this](http://www.codexworld.com/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-ajax-php/)

Comment: Thank you very much sir!
Your answer solved completely!